# Change the colour of an image with PHP

Tags: php

I have a picture like this: https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/internet-and-web-4/78/internt_web_technology-08-512.png, and I want to change image to switch that black color with color I provide. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes. With PHP (probably using GD or Imagemagick), or you could probably do it with Javascript and Canvas operations. These days you may even be able to do it with CSS image filtering, or use SVG instead of a PNG. Or pre-prepare some variations in advance and just swap them in. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I searched for GD lib, and did not get any idea what should i do. In which format i need to convert first image. I want to convert in some type of code, to search for colors inside it and change black with color i want. But don't know how to write that, and where to look? Any idea? So, it's posible right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple GD example in PHP that might help you get started. Viewed in a browser it'll show you a red version of that image. You'll need to have the original PNG file in the same directory.

Bear in mind that GD and other image manipulation (especially on transparent images) are really quite complicated subjects; there's a lot to learn and going through a few basic tutorials, even if they don't seem to be directly related to what you want to achieve, might really help your understanding.

```
<?php

// Load the image into $img
$img = imagecreatefrompng('internt_web_technology-08-512.png');

// Because your chosen image has transparency, we need to make sure
// we save the alpha channel information.
imageSaveAlpha($img, true);

// Filter the image to mid-red (RGB values 127, 0, 0) using the
// "colourize" filter. This works nicely with your chosen image
// because it's a shape with a uniform dark colour.
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 127, 0, 0);  

// Make sure our content type is PNG, otherwise it'll just
// display the image data as text.
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Output to browser.
imagepng($img);
```

Example input:

[image: Small version of example image for posterity]

Example output:

[image: Output of my example script]

Comment: Thank you. I started to think in a good way with this example i think :)This really helped me.